# Alternative Font?

Tags: typography, font-identification

I am trying to find an alternative to this font as the download license has been suspended.

It doesn't have to be identical but I would like something as close as possible if I can; I have tried several online ID-ing services but none have been able to get me to anything even close.

http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1203003/db_oleum

I am hoping to use this for an in-game (video game) company, so a commercial license (even if it is premium) will be required, but right now I'd just like to find a suitable equivalent that I can download, and deal with the rest later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[La Pipo](http://usfonts.gestalten.com/pipo.html) might be a nice alternative font:

[image]

Bendliner 2013 is another alternative but, unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a place to download it. You might be able to reach out to the designer on [Behance (Michael Golovachev - Scorpy Design Studio)](https://www.behance.net/scorpy) to see if it's available:

[image]